# Magento using operators in where clauses

Tags: database, magento, zend-framework

My products have `date_created` and `expires_in` attributes. `date_created` is Magento date backend format while `expires_in` is a select that contains options as 1 week, 1 month etc.

Using those two attributes I'm trying to determine the total number of expired products. My idea was to write a query that selects:

1. products where date created + 1 week < now() AND expires_in = 1 week
   AND
2. products where date created + 1 month < now() AND expires_in = 1 month
3. ...

But I don't seem to be able to make even the first part of the first step to work:

```
$currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
$oneWeekTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(strtotime("+1 week"));

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addAttributeToSelect('')
...
//these are what i have tried so far:
$products->addAttributeToFilter('date_updated + ' . $oneWeekTimestamp , array('gt' => $currentTimestamp));
$products->addAttributeToFilter(new Zend_Db_Expr('date_updated + ' . $oneWeekTimestamp), array('gt' => $currentTimestamp));
$products->addAttributeToFilter("DATEDIFF($currentTimestamp, 'date_updated')" , array('gt' => 7));

$countExpired = $products -> count();
```

None of them seem to work. If possible I'd like the cross RDBMS solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way:

```
 $currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
 $oneWeekTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(strtotime("+1 week"));

 $oneweekDate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$oneWeekTimestamp);

 $products->addAttributeToFilter('date_updated',array('date'=>true,'gt',$oneweekDate);
```